# Help in understanding Stormer's theorem proof

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I am reading the following proof of Stormer's theorem:

http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~klazar/stormer.pdf

Let $S$ be a set of primes, and $\overline{S}$ the integers it generates ($n \in \overline{S}$ if all its prime factors are $\in S$)

They show that if $y$, $y+1$ $\in \overline{S}$, then there exists a solution for the Pell equation
$a^2-db^2=1$ where $a$,$b\in \overline{S}$, and $d\in \overline{S}$ with prime exponents between $0$ and $2$ (i.e. no $n^3$ divides $d$)

In page 3, they say

> "Since $a_1$ is coprime with $d$, we
>   see that $c_2 = 2^r$ and $a_1 = 2^{r−1}$
>   . If $r ≥ 2$ then $2$ divides both $d$ and $a_1$, which
>   is impossible. Thus $r = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$, which is impossible either. If $p ≥ 5$ then
>   again $c_p$ divides $b_m$, is a $d$-number and each prime factor of $c_p$ divides $p{a_1}^{p−1}$.
>   From $(a_1, d) = 1$ it follows that $c_p$ has the only prime factor $p$ and $c_p = p^r$,
>   $r ∈ N$. Since $p > 3$, the second summand in the identity (with $l = p$) is divisible
>   by $p^2$ (as $p$ divides ${\binom{p}{3}}$
>   and $d$) and the following ones are clearly divisible by $p^2$ as well. Thus if $r ≥ 2$ then $p^2$ divides also the first summand $p{a_1}^{p−1}$
>   and $p$ divides $a_1$ and $d$, which is impossible. Hence $r = 1$. But then $p = c_p = p{a_1}^{p−1}+ . . .$
>   which is impossible either as $a1 > 1$."

I don't understand the following 2 things:

1. Why since $a_1$ is co prime with d, do we see that $c_2 = 2^r$? Same for other primes when they say claim $c_p$ is a power of $p$.

2.Why is $d$ divisble by $2$ (and $p$ in the latter case)?

I would very much like to understand the proof, thanks.

Comment: @user1952009 it's a^2-db^2, every pair of y,y+1 gives rise to a solution to the equation for some d as described and a,b in S with a stick over it.

Comment: it seems obvious I and you understood nothing, since there are both $S$ numbers and $d$ numbers.

Comment: @user1952009 There are no $S$ numbers, $S$ is a set of primes, a $d$ number is one that has all it's prime factors in $S$ (you asked for this to be written as {\overline{S}} )

For some reason they also used $d$ as the variable name in the pell equation, which is why I think your notation is better with ${\overline{S}}$, is that more clear?

Comment: For 1, the logic is unnecessarily long-winded  We have that $c_2$ (hence also $\frac12 c_2$) is a $d$-number and that $\frac12 c_2$ divides $d$.  But the only $d$-number that divides $d$ is $1$, so $\frac12 c_2 = 1$.  The author is writing $c_2 = 2^r$ as a way of saying "the only prime dividing $c_2$ is $2$", but in fact we can just as easily deduce a unique value for $c_2$ rather than saying something more general.  The intent of the author is likely to harmonize the presentation of this case with the $p$ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, the logic is unnecessarily long-winded.  We have that $c_2$ (hence also $\frac12 c_2$) is a $d$-number and that $\frac12 c_2$ is relatively prime to $d$.  But the only $d$-number that is relatively prime to $d$ is $1$, so $\frac12 c_2 = 1$.  The author is writing $c_2 = 2^r$ as a way of saying "the only prime dividing $c_2$ is $2$", but in fact we can just as easily deduce a unique value for $c_2$ rather than saying something more general.  The intent of the author was probably just to harmonize the presentation of this case with the $p$ case, which I'll explain next.

We have that every prime dividing $c_p$ is a divisor of $pa_1^{p-1}$, and that every prime dividing $c_p$ is a divisor of $d$.  But $d$ and $a_1$ have no common factor, so there is never a prime dividing both $d$ and $a_1^{p-1}$, so we can exclude any prime divisor of $a_1^{p-1}$ from being a prime dividing $c_p$.  This leaves $p$ as the only possible prime divisor of $pa_1^{p-1}$ that could possibly divide $c_p$.

Comment: Why does $c_p$ divide $d$?

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis Oops, I meant to say something else.  Fixed.

Comment: :( I can't see any of the divisibility arguments, does everything follow from the equation for $c_l$? I don't see why every prime divisor of $c_p$ is a divisor of $p{a_1}^{p-1}$ and $d$ (I understand that if you show it divides $d$ than it divides $p{a_1}^{p-1}$, but dividing $d$ remains elusive to me).

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis If that's the case then you really should have specified this level of detail in your question.

Comment: Well I didn't know that it was true (they don't claim that), I only need that part and then I'm good, why does every divisor of $c_p$ divide $d$?

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis Yes they do claim that: what do you think $d$-number means?  (it's defined in the paper)

Comment: omg I'm so stupid, I read about it in a lot of other places and was used to talk about a set and a number being a d-number when it's from the set. Now everything is clear. sorry for wasting everyone's time :\ I swear I'm typically not that careless.